# Re-Import Exported Armature

Tags: rigging, armature

After I export my armature and reimport it to Blender some bones have scale problems. Fortunately, basically it doesn't have any effect on the rig because the pivot point remains the same on every bone, but it looks weird. Could it be an import problem to blender? Works fine if it's imported into UE.

Comment: The concept of "bone length" only exists in Blender and almost certainly not in whatever format you're exporting to, so you should expect it to be lost after a re-import.

Comment: Thanks, so it's natural. The exported file format is FBX.